# SymPy: How do I evaluate an expression with constants?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have this differential equation written in SymPy

```
diffeq = Eq(f(x).diff(x, x) - 2*f(x).diff(x) + f(x), sin(x))
```

where f(x) is a symbol Function symbol and x is a variable symbol.

When I solve it with this:

```
expr = dsolve(diffeq, f(x))
```

I get

```
f(x)=(C_1+C_2x)ex+12cos(x)
```

Which is the correct solution to this equation. But now I would like to evaluate this function in several points. I know I can substitute the x with the subs function, but is there a way to substitute the constant values C_1 and C_2 so I can evaluate the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open [PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11264) for this on GitHub, that would add an `ics` flag to `dsolve`.

For now, you can substitute the values manually using `subs`, use `solve` to solve for `C1` and `C2`, and use `subs` to substitute the values back into the solution.

For example, if `f(0) = 1` and `f'(0) = 0`, you'd use something like

```
>>> p1 = expr.subs([(x, 0), (f(0), 1)])
>>> dexpr = Eq(expr.lhs.diff(x), expr.rhs.diff(x))
>>> p2 = dexpr.subs([(x, 0), (f(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0), 0)])
>>> p1
Eq(1, C1 + 1/2)
>>> p2
Eq(0, C1 + C2)
>>> C1, C2 = symbols('C1 C2')
>>> sol = solve([p1, p2], [C1, C2])
>>> sol
{C1: 1/2, C2: -1/2}
>>> expr.subs(sol)
Eq(f(x), (-x/2 + 1/2)*exp(x) + cos(x)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your constants from your expression. It's a bit messy, but it works:

```
v1 = expr.args[1].args[1].args[0].args[0]
v2 = expr.args[1].args[1].args[0].args[1].args[0]
expr.subs(v1,1).subs(v2,2)
```

Explanation:
Have a look at `expr.args`. It is a tuple the left and the right hand side of the equation. Here we want the second entry of the tuple, thus index 1.
We then get some `sympy.core.add.Add`. This we can again decompose using `args` and can continue until we reach our constants.